# SharePoint 2013 cmscore resource wrong translation for List_Pages_UrlName

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, csom, resource-files, multilingual

I am using CSOM to get dutch translation of the '**List_Pages_UrlName**' field in cmscore.nl-NL.resx resource file from the Dutch language pack.

```
// Get the language of the web
var context = web.Context;
int language = (int)web.EnsureProperty(w => w.Language);

// Retrieve the pages url string
var result = Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities.Utility.GetLocalizedString(context, "$Resources:List_Pages_UrlName", "cmscore", language);
context.ExecuteQueryRetry();

string pagesLibraryName = result.Value;
```

The value it's returning is:

> Pagina`s

This is wrong. The correct url of the pages list is:

> paginas

Does anyone know where i can report such an issue? So it might be fixed in some upade eventually?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Hi @GautamSheth, Maybe i wasn't clear enough in my post. But the **cmscore.nl-NL.resx** is provided by the Dutch Language pack for SharePoint 2013. So it isn't possible to change the value in the file. I know the correct url is `paginas` and that is the value I expect the resource file to return, but unfortunately it is returning an incorrect value.

Comment: The key is actually **List_Pages_UrlName**. Nothing you could do about that.
So your code is correct. I wonder why cmscore is wrong. Paul